# Webworks 2.0 add a custom plugin in java

Tags: java, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I wanted to know if it was possible to add a custom JAVA plugin in a webworks app for BB 10 ?

Because I've got my app created since a long time now and I'm trying to upgrade to the 2.0 but my plugin isn't working..

Is there is a way to do it ? since we have to do it in C/C++ as they say here : https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/about_custom_native_plugins_cordova_blackberry.html

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  The Java J2ME runtime that existed on older BlackBerry devices (e.g. BB 5.0, BB6 or BB7) does not exist on BlackBerry 10.

The plugin would need to be ported to C/C++.

For help, see the 'Template' example in Github:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, I'll do it in C/C++ then.